# How to use UITabarViewController in Xcode - OBjectiveC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

my code:

```
UIView *screen=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
screen.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
UIView *screen2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
screen.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
screen2.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

UITabBarController *tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
[tab setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:screen,screen2, nil]];

self.view=tab.view;
```

but when I run it has Exception at: [[tab setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:screen,screen2, nil]];

Can anybode tell me why?, i'm beginner
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are adding UIView to your tabbar view controllers. You should add view controllers like UIViewControllers. this shows how you can add uitabbarcontroller programatically [link](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/08/adding-uitabbarcontroller-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

a UITabBarController viewControllers property is an array of UIViewController's not UIViews, you need to initialise the array with view controllers instead of views

[The view controller programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1) is a good place to start reading about this

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController have a List of tabs, each tab is uiviewcontroller or navigationViewController.
also you need to give the selectedTab for first opening.